# How do I loop through a json collection of strings with Mustache?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mustache

The MVC that creates the array of strings is

```
  public JsonResult GetInvalidFilesAJAX(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        string[] invalidFiles = new string[] { "one.xls", "two.xls", "three.xls" };

        return Json(new
        {
            Status = "OK",
            InvalidFiles = invalidFiles
        });
    }
```

And the javascript that should loop through and print out each string is

```
  $.ajax(
                          {
                              type: 'POST',
                              url: 'http://localhost:7000/ManualProcess/GetInvalidFilesAJAX',
                              success: function (response) {
                                  if (response.Status == 'OK') {
                                      //Use template to populate dialog with text of Tasks to validate
                                      var results = {
                                          invalidFiles: response.InvalidFiles,
                                      };
                                      var template = "<b>Invalid Files:</b> {{#invalidFiles}} Filename: {{invalidFiles.value}} <br />{{/invalidFiles}}";
                                      var html = Mustache.to_html(template, results);

                                      $('#divDialogModalErrors').html('ERROR: The following files have been deleted:');
                                      $('#divDialogModalErrorFiles').html(html);
```

How do I refer to the string in the array? The way above is not correct. All the example I find seem to be for when the Jason collection has property names.. in my case it is just a key value pair (I guess?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way. You must convert the JSON into an array or loop through the data yourself, e.g,

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Assuming JSON.parse is available
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0, value; (value = data[i]); ++i) {
  arr.push(value);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var arr = [];
for (var prop in data){
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    arr.push({
      'key' : prop,
      'value' : data[prop]
    });
  }
}
```

And then to display it:

```
var template = "{{#arr}}<p>{{value}}</p>{{/arr}}";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, {arr: arr});
```

This is assuming your JSON Object is one level deep.

Comment: I can't get the line below to work.. what exactly should I be putting in place of 'jsonString' ?     var data = JSON.parse(response.InvalidFiles);

Comment: @punkouter Your JSON string you recieved in response. If it is already a JSON object then just put `data = object`. Can you `console.log(response.InvalidFiles)` for me?

Comment: one.xls,two.xls,three.xls.. so I guess it is a javascript array and not a JSON object right ?

Comment: got it! your second example worked.. Im new and not clear on how objects are structured exactly being passed from C# to javascript.